# Visual studio errors/suggestions about async syntax

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asynchronous, visual-studio-2015

I have a method that I am declaring as an asych method. The code is listed below.

```
private async Task<string> tempPassword()
{
    char[] hashes = "ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRUVWXY34689!?@$#".ToCharArray();
    Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    List<char> bits = new List<char>();
    while (bits.Count < 7)
    {
         int i = r.Next(0, hashes.Length);
         if (!bits.Contains(hashes[i]))
              bits.Add(hashes[i]);
    }
    return string.Join("", bits.ToArray());
}
```

While this code is correct and compiles, Visual Studio gives me the following feedback:

> This async method lacks await operators and will run synchroniously.
>   Consider using the await operators to await non-blocking API Calls, or
>   'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-Bound work on a background thread.

While I do not have a wealth of background with async (which is why I am using it, to be honest, so I will learn) it doesn't seem to me like there is anything in this method that would require an await operator so I am a bit kerfuffled as to what it is I am supposed to be awaiting.

Comment: There is nothing async in your code, so it shouldn't be marked as async. That's what the compiler tries to tell you. Just change the signature to `private string tempPassword()`

Answer (score 1):

> it doesn't seem to me like there is anything in this method that would require an await operator

In that case, why is the method `async` in the first place? You only need `async` if you use `await`. In its current state, the method will execute synchronously, and return an already completed `Task<string>`. If you don't expect it to ever need to be asynchronous, you can change it's signature to just return `string`. If you do expect it to become asynchronous in the future (or if you can't change the return type because you're implementing an interface or overriding a method from the base class), you can remove the `async` modifier, and explicitly return a completed task:

```
return Task.FromResult(string.Join("", bits.ToArray()));
```

This will avoid the overhead of creating an async state machine.